# Hide igGrid Summary Total

Tags: infragistics, summary, ignite-ui, iggrid

Is there a way to hide the igGrid Summary Total row as the default on opening of the page?
I have looked everywhere on the Infragistics developer forum and cannot find anything.
Anyone come up with a solution to this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the igGrids, I've never used them.

I did some reading on summary rows, and it looks likes you actually have to add code to have them show up. They are called Column Summaries. Here's a reference, if it helps.

http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/jQuery/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/igGrid_Features_Landing_Page.html

Answer (score 0):

To hide the summary row:

```js
$("#gridName").igGridSummaries("toggleSummariesRows", false, null);
```

This gets tricky when dealing with Hierarchical grids but this pseudo code should work for that:

```js
foreach primaryKeyValue in myDataSource
    $("#gridName_" + primaryKeyValue +"_" + subgridkey +"_child").igGridSummaries("toggleSummariesRows", false, null);
```